# Unable to resolve target 'android-18' error

Tags: android

[image: i am unable to download target android-18 file]

i am unable to download target android-18 file

Comment: The app you have downloaded runs on SDK version 18. and you might not have that updated SDK also. best is right click on your project-->go to properties==?Android-->select 2.2 or 4.0 which is 8 or 14 or you can choose any version of your choice which is available there and make sure you have the corresponding device with you to run the app. For eg: if you select android 3.0. then you got to run the app in a tablet.

Comment: @Sherry I had the same problem. Try installing version 17.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In ``default.properties` file .

set `target=android-18`.

Check also that you installed this API level and check it in properties window, like:

[image]

In my case 17 is selected

Comment: if you don't see the API level you're looking for, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771662/eclipse-adt-plugin-no-build-target-available-resolved

Answer (score 10):

Right click on your project select Properties(Alt+Enter),
goto Android(Project build Target)-> Check `Android 4.2.2` or earlier version which you have, click on Apply-> OK, that's it.

finally clean your project, Done!!

Answer (score 2):

1. First open Android SDK Manager and check whehther API18 (Android 4.3) SDK platform is downloaded or not. If not download it by selecting check box then accept license and press install package.
2. Next close and open eclipse again.
3. now it will show  API18 (Android 4.3) SDK platform in  Android SDK Manager as installed.
4. after that select project -> Properties -> Android -> mark checkbox Android 4.3 in project build target ->apply ->ok.
5. select project -> project-> clean.

Answer (score 1):

I thing u r importing Project in eclipse some Android Project Not Find Target sdk So we Add target sdk like Right Click on ProJect GO To Properties GO to Android and Select Taget if Not Install than Download Adt plugin For Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The error is well justified, either you dont have correct properties added or you are missing the SDK.

Please check this link,

[Unable to resolve target 'android-XX'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15)

Hope it helps

Comment: its for 15. m unable to do the same for 18